# Strip first 9 characters off filename in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I need to strip the first 9 characters off filename in windows batch file.

The filename format that I need the characters stripped off is

`0009mmdd_abcd_abcdefgh_00009_yyyymmddhhmmss.dat`

I tried using the following but it does not work

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%a in ('dir /b *.dat') do (
  SET oldName = %%a
  SET newName = %oldName:~9%
  echo %%a
  echo %oldName%
  echo %newName%
  echo !newname!
)
```

The output it get is

```
SET oldName = 00091017_abcd_abcdefgh_00009_20141021111145.dat
 SET newName = ~9
 echo 00091017_abcd_abcdefgh_00009_20141021111145.dat
 echo
 echo
 echo !newname!
)
00091017_abcd_abcdefgh_00009_20141021111145.dat
ECHO is on.
ECHO is on.
ECHO is on.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you know about and use delayed expansion. Just do it consequent: `set newname=!oldname:~9!` (and take out the spaces in your `set` commands).

Answer (score 1):

If your real problem is to strip the string before the first underscore:

```
setlocal
for /f "tokens=1*delims=_" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b *.dat') do (
 echo(ren "%%a_%%b" "%%b"
)
```

Note: assumes that portion up to first underscore is to be deleted.

instructions merely `echo`ed for testing purposes. change `echo(ren` to `ren` to actually do the rename.

`a-d` added to `dir` command to exclude directorynames.

Comment: Magoo, You are a genius.  Your solution worked perfectly.  Thank you all for responding quickly to my reqeust.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET oldName = %%a
SET newName = %oldName:~9%
             ^ Space included in value
           ^   Space included in variable name
```

So, you are defining two variables called `%oldName %` and `%newName %`. Try with

```
@echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b *.dat') do (
      SET "oldName=%%a"
      SET "newName=!oldName:~9!"
      echo %%a
      echo !oldName!
      echo !newname!
    )
```